# Access data from LabelInput using Google Closure

Tags: javascript, html, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am trying to read input got through autocomplete and display it as a alert. After accessing i get undefined as alert instead of the value accessed through labelinput.

The ex.js file is as follows

```
goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.ui.LabelInput');
goog.require('goog.ui.ac');
goog.require('goog.events.EventType');
function autoComplete() {
    var jobj = [{"cityname":"Bangalore","cityid":"1"},
    {"cityname":"Bellary","cityid":"2"},
    {"cityname":"Belgaum","cityid":"3"},
    {"cityname":"Bidar","cityid":"4"},
    {"cityname":"Mumbai","cityid":"5"},
    {"cityname":"Munnar","cityid":"6"},
    {"cityname":"Delhi","cityid":"7"},
    {"cityname":"Diu/Daman","cityid":"8"}];
    var li1 = new goog.ui.LabelInput("Enter City Name");
        li1.render(goog.dom.getElement('d1'));
    var array1 = new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<jobj.length; i++)
        {
        array1[i] = jobj[i].cityname;
        }
    var ac2 = goog.ui.ac.createSimpleAutoComplete(
        array1, goog.dom.getElement('d1'), false);
    goog.events.listen(ac2,
        goog.ui.ac.AutoComplete.EventType.UPDATE,
        function() { var val2 = (goog.dom.getElement('d1').value);
        alert(val2);
        });
}
```

The ex.html file is as follows

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script> <!--My Closure Library Location -->
    <script src="ex.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="autoComplete();">
    <style>
        .ac-renderer {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
        <div id="d1">City &nbsp </div><br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"goog.dom.getElement('d1')" will return a div element, which will not have a value. The LabelInput renders a control inside of that element when you call

```
li1.render(goog.dom.getElement('d1'));
```

You should be using the getValue method of the LabelInput class itself

```
li1.getValue()
```

or if you want to access the Input element created during the LabelInput render method, call

```
li1.getElement().value
```

Source  : http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_ui_LabelInput.html